# How to detect a first app launching and display an instruction screen?

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, walkthrough

I am developing a walkthrough screen which should appear only the first time when the user opens the app. So far I created the walkthrough page and PageViewController.
See the picture:
[image]

I read lots of similar questions here and I understood that I have to use

```
  UserDefaults()
```

inside the AppDelegate, but I didn't understand how to use the class and storyboard names inside the code.
Basically, when the app is opened for the first time, the PageViewController should appear on the screen and when the user clicks on the start button, which is on the WalkThroughScreen it will dismiss the tutorial page and the app will start.

I have tried this code:

```
if let isFirstStart = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "isFirstLaunch") as? Bool {
  if defaults.bool(forKey: "isFirstLaunch") {
    defaults.set(false, forKey: "isFirstLaunch")
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "WalkThroughScreen", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc : WalkThroughScreen = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! WalkThroughScreen
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
```

I am pretty sure that it is a complete mess, because I didn't understand it very good and I haven't used the TutorialPage, so I will be very thankful if someone leave me hints or example how to do it correctly

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are right, you have to use `userDefaults` to achieve this. And you have to do it inside `appDelegate()`
Roel Koops answer should do it but you can try it like this also:

```
  let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
    if launchedBefore  {
        print("This is not first launch.")
    } else {
        print("This is first launch.")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc : WalkThroughScreen = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkThroughScreen") as! WalkThroughScreen
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

And make sure to declare: `let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard` and use it inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

There are even more solutions so I give you one more:

```
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if !userDefaults.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore") {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc : WelcomeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkThroughScreen") as! WelcomeViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
        userDefaults.synchronize()

    }
```

You can even declare all the storyboard thing in one line:

```
self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkThroughScreen")
```

But this assumes that you declare 2 variables:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var storyboard: UIStoryboard?
```

If it didn't work just tell me, I am gonna try to help.

Comment: if this code is placed in appDelegate() as Tarvo Mäesepp is suggesting, then it needs a little bit modification: self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

Comment: Hey I can't make it working,because I am mixing the vc name and the identifier name. May I send you the app to take a quick look?

Comment: I used the same identifiers you gave us. But yes you can send it.

Comment: You can download it from here:
http://www.filedropper.com/uipageviewcontrollerexample-master2

Comment: Thank you very much man! It is a sample so that I get the basics and the try to do it by my own. Please share it with me again, so that I can start it on my mac in stead of replacing only the code :)

Comment: I have to say that your code is total mess but here you go: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B587oI34VXz3Z1BBNXFWNEFUTkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks man, I download it and tested, but I do not see the Walkthrough screen. When I start the app, I am directly opening the initial view controller. Then I deleted the app to simulate the first Launch and again I see only the initial view. Have you tested it ?

Comment: You have to delete you lr app because otherwise it doesn't understand taht it is first launch... and the key is false. I yested and it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127273/discussion-between-dakata-and-tarvo-maesepp).

Answer (score 2):

The code in your if-block is never executed if the key "isFirstLaunch" doesn't exist.

Try this:

```
    if let isFirstStart = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "isFirstLaunch") as? Bool {
        print("this is not the first launch")
    } else {
        print("this is the first launch")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isFirstLaunch")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc : WalkThroughScreen = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkThroughScreen") as! WalkThroughScreen
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Would you please check are the names of the storyboards and the classes are properly used?

Comment: See my updated answer. The name of the main storyboard is "Main" by default in the templates. if you didn't change that, above code should by right.

Comment: I get an error in the last line: there is no member of type "present"

Comment: Are you using this code in your AppDelegate? Then you need to present like this: self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

Comment: where exactly should this code be kept in Appdelegate class?